# FB.Event.subscribe auth.statusChange not working

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-graph-api

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'MyAppId',
        channelURL : 'MyChannelUrl',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response)
    {
        console.log(response.status);
    }
}
```

Why does my console.log only triggers, if i am currently logged in on Facebook ?

Answer (score 0):

auth.statusChange will fire only if:

- Connected (response.status === 'connected')
- Logged into Facebook but not connected with your application (response.status === 'not_authorized')
- Not logged into Facebook at all.

Connected = the user is logged in and has authenticated your app, and response.authResponse supplies the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed request, and the time the access token and signed request each expire

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/